# yo meanjs error - Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd test7 && npm install

Tags: node.js, meanjs, yo

i am trying to learn nodejs and want to create a boiler plate code for me to make further modification. I am using yeomen and meanjs for the same but I am facing following issue:

command -> yo meanjs

error ->

```
undefined
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? master
master
? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be changed later. test7
Cloning the MEAN repo.......
? What would you like to call your application? MEAN
? How would you describe your application? Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js
? How would you describe your application in comma seperated key words? MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js
? What is your company/author name? 
? Would you like to generate the article example CRUD module? Yes
? Would you like to generate the chat example module? Yes
   create test7/package.json
   create test7/bower.json
   create test7/config/env/default.js
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd test7 && npm install
npm WARN package.json mean@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"4.0.0","npm":"2.14.2"})
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency istanbul@0.x.x included from grunt-mocha-istanbul will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
```

Please note that this is subset of the error.

Please let me know what am i missing.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: which node version, and OS  are you using?. for me works on OSX 10.11  with Node v0.12.7.

Answer (score 0):

"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"

Seems that you need to downgrade your NodeJs Version in between 0.8 ~ 0.12
Also The Npm

Comment: Looks like maybe version alignment between components is high maintenance in the MEAN stack?  Is this a taste of things to come?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sorry for the delay. Either you have to downgrade or download a zip version from github which worked for me. I deleted what I don't want and it worked fine for me. Yo generator with new nose version for mean. Js is work in progress as far as I know.